# Calling Methods dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, module, gettype

I am trying to call methods dynamically and I have issues. Could some one please help

I have the following vb code

```
Module
    Sub Main
        if user-input = RP1 then
            createRP1()
        elseif user-input = RP2 then 
            createRP2()
        end if
    end sub

    sub createRP1()
        ...
    end sub

    sub createRP2()
        ,...
    end sub

End Module
```

The CreateRP1/CreateRP2 method does not have any arguments. There are some n number of reports. So I do not want to write all those if or switch conditions for this. I want to write some thing simple so I tried this

```
1 Dim type As Type = "["GetType"]"()
2 Dim method As MethodInfo = type.GetMethod("Create" + user-input)
3 If method IsNot Nothing Then
4     method.Invoke(Me, Nothing)
5 End If
```

Line 1 and 4 are not working
Line 4 is not working because "me" does not go with module. But how to rewrite 1? I saw this somewhere in StackOverflow site

Comment: Does createRP2 take arguments? You can use optional parameters in VB if you need to pass a param that may/may not exist. Trying to understand exactly what your code does before I can offer a true answer...

Comment: None of the methods take arguments. They are the methods that create rdlc reports based on Report numbers. User will input Report numbers and we have to generate reports for them. There are around 20+ reports everything is working fine. I just want to replace those if conditions which are getting bigger as the report number increases.

Comment: I guess I do not understand what your code is actually trying to accomplish... you are just trying to dynamically call subs ? Or something more?

Comment: Yes I want to call those subs dynamically. I just want to replace that if block with something better.

Comment: Well I would say you shouldn't make one sub for each type of document. Create a report object and a function which can create those objects if passed a valid document number. Otherwise you will always have to create more and more subs to create new documents. At that point the ifelse chain will be the least of your code worries. It might be a bit more work then you were expecting..

Comment: "Create a report object and a function which can create those objects if passed a valid document number" So I am passing that document number and I am getting that number from user. So at some point I am ending up writing code for determining which report should be generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `Type` of the current `Module` like this:

```
 Dim myType As Type = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
```

Since it's a `Module`, all of the methods are essentially `Shared` (e.g. static, non-instance methods), so you can just pass `Nothing` for the `obj` parameter of the `MethodInfo.Invoke` method:

```
 Dim methodName As String = "Create" & userInput
 Dim method As MethodInfo = myType.GetMethod(methodName)
 method.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)
```

However, rather than using reflection, you may also want to consider using a dictionary of delegates so that it would be more deterministic and type-checked at compile time.  For instance:

```
Dim methods As New Dictionary(Of String, Action)
methods.Add("RP1", AddressOf CreateRP1)
methods.Add("RP2", AddressOf CreateRP1)
' ...
methods(userInput).Invoke()
```

Comment: +1, far better then my answer... this would be the easiest for you to implement as well. Did not think to use a dictionary of delegates.

Comment: Thanks. Dim myType worked. But its failing at method.Invoke(nothing,Nothing). It says Objects reference not set....

Comment: Must be it's not finding the method by the given name?  Check to make sure that the method variable isn't null.

Comment: If it's not finding it, it's probably because the method is in a different module or because the method is private.  If the method is private, you need to pass `BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static` to the `bindingAttr` parameter of `myType.GetMethod`.

Comment: Perfect. Just the way I wanted. after adding bindingattr it worked. Thanks a lot you just saved my time.

Comment: I liked the Solution using Reflection. But which one is good reflection or dictionary ? I mean performance wise.

Comment: Performance?  I couldn't say for sure but my educated guess is that the hash table look up to find the delegate in the dictionary is going to be significantly faster than the reflection and dynamic type checking of the first solution would be.

Comment: The primary benefit of the reflection solution is less coding and self discovery, not performance. In other words, when you add a new method, it will just work. You won't have to also add a delegate to it in a dictionary or anything. But it's not type-checked at compile time, so that could lead to runtime errors if you aren't careful. It's also less self-documenting. Developers working on the code would just have to know that they need to name the method a certain thing, but that wouldn't necessarily be clear.

Comment: However, if sheer performance is the ultimate goal, then I'm afraid to say that a Select Case block is almost certainly faster than even the Dictionary solution.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks much for the clarification. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to create a "Report" object through designing a class. Then you could easily make things on the fly.

```
function (byRef user-input As String) As Report
    if not "s" & user-input = "s" 
        Dim user-report As Report = new Report(user-input)
    end if
end function
```

Then your Report class

```
Private reportNumber As String
Private data As String
Public Sub New(byVal reportNumber As String) 
      Sub createRP(byRef repotNumber As String)
      // use report # here to select the correct data... 
      // so if it was sql.... 
      // "SELECT data FROM report_table where report_num =" & reportNumber
      end Sub
end Sub
```

Comment: I get What you are saying. While Designing Report class ,if I am writing the constructor with user-input am I not doing the same thing...it just appears to me that the location of the code is changing but I am doing same thing again

Comment: So to get the data for the report I already have methods to do it. So in my case I am writing around 20 + cases which I am trying to avoid. If there is no better solution then I can go for it. I was just wondering if I can do something with few lines of code.

Comment: Yes, the only way to avoid having all your functions and else/if is to use logic to determine the Report # inside of your sub which creates the returned result. As far as I know at least. I am not a wizard, and someone else may know better.

Comment: I've added an SQL psuedo-example from what I was trying to show you. I don't know how this applies to creating rdlc reports, because I've never done that. But I'm sure you understand the logic. Best of luck

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me out. I got the problem solved from Steven